# Почему переменная становится None?

Tags: python-3.x, парсер

Пишу парсер сайта. Отдельной функцией определяю число страниц, на которые разложена нужная мне таблица. Проверяю переменную на выходе. Но когда в main начинается цикл for, переменная page_compan оказывается None. Что я не так делаю?

```
def get_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text

# Функция возвращает число страниц, на которых разложена таблица с данными об УК данного города. 
def get_page_compan (html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    try:
        end_but = soup.find('ul', class_='pagination').find_all('a', class_='')[-1].get('href')
        end_but = int(end_but.split('=')[1])
        print("Последняя кнопка указывает на страницу номер", end_but)
        prev_but = soup.find('ul', class_='pagination').find_all('a', class_='')[-2].get('href')
        prev_but = int(prev_but.split('=')[1])
        print("Предпоследняя кнопка показывает на страницу номер", prev_but)

# Сравниваем, на какой кнопке большее число?
        if end_but < prev_but:
            page_compan = prev_but 

        elif prev_but < end_but:
            page_compan = end_but

        elif prev_but == end_but:
            page_compan = end_but

# Проверяем, какого типа переменная page_compan и переводим её в строку
        print (type(page_compan))
        page_compan = str(page_compan) 
        print (type(page_compan))
        print("Список УК этого города составлен на", page_compan, "страницах") 

    except IndexError:
        page_compan = None
        print("Список УК этого города составлен на одной странице")

def main():
    url = 'http://gosjkh.ru/company/sverdlovskaya-oblast/kamensk-uralskij'
    page_part = '?page='
    page_compan = get_page_compan(get_html(url))

    if page_compan is None:
        print('page_compan is None')

    for i in range(1, page_compan):
        url_gen1 = url + page_part + str(i)
        print(url_gen1)
```

На выходе получаю:

```
parser is being run directly
Последняя кнопка указывает на страницу номер 2
Предпоследняя кнопка показывает на страницу номер 3
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
Список УК этого города составлен на 3 страницах
page_compan is None
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-883e63132ac7> in <module>()
     58 if __name__ == '__main__':
     59     print('parser is being run directly')
---> 60     main()
     61 else:
     62     print('parser is being imported into another module')

<ipython-input-21-883e63132ac7> in main()
     50         print('page_compan is None')
     51 
---> 52     for i in range(1, page_compan):
     53         url_gen1 = url + page_part + str(i)
     54         print(url_gen1)

TypeError: 'NoneType' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что функция get_page_compan не возвращает никакого значения.

Добавьте в неё `return page_compan` и будет вам счастье.

Comment: О, май год! @Александр, я счастлив и ещё чутка продвинулся. Спасибо вам!

Comment: Если ответ решил вашу проблему, вы можете нажать галочку слева от него, чтобы отметить его как решение. На данном сайте считается хорошим тоном всегда поступать так.

Comment: Усвоил, спасибо.